# Ajustar texto en tableview Javafx

Tags: javafx

Estoy Llenando una tabla con datos, pero hay una columna que se llama observaciones en las que el texto muchas veces es muy largo y se sale de la celda.Quisiera saber de que forma puedo hacer que la celda se expanda hacia abajo y muestre el texto completo ,como en excel se usa el ajustar texto.

algo como este codigo:

[Codigo para renderizar](https://jluger.de/blog/20160731_javafx_text_rendering_in_tableview.html)

Lo intente implementar pero me sale un error en el initialize:

col_obserrvaciones.setCellFactory(WRAPPING_CELL_FACTORY);

no me toma el setCellFactory ,me lo arca en error.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma mas simple de hacer esto es empleando css con la tabla para que le de formato al texto

```
.table-view .cell{ // modificas de la tabla los parámetros de cada celda
-fx-wrap-text: true;  /*estableces que el texto dentro del label de la celda pueda ser divido en partes*/
-fx-cell-size: 60px ;/* fijas la altura de la celda. Prueba con varios valores para que veas el efecto*/
-fx-pref-width: 40px; /* Estableces el ancho del label dentro de la celda.*/

 }
```